# Compiling Qt5 code for Centos 5.6

Tags: c++, linux, centos, cross-compiling, qt5

**TLDR**:
VMWare virtual machine, Centos 5.6, gcc 4.8.1, Qt5 fully compiled.

Any Qt5 compatible QtCreator refuses to work due to the lack of opengl. Need help either making it work or advice on how to cross compile from Centos 6 to Centos 5 or on how to set up some other app to work with Qt5 code.

**Detailed**:
In a bit of a bind here - we have an app that is deployed to Centos version 5.6. It's quite old but upgrading is out of the question atm. It wouldn't be a problem but for 1 thing - I compile stuff for it on VMWare virtual machine and the linux kernel of this machine is too old to support vmgfx and provide OpenGL for versions of qtcreator that actually support qt5.

Its not *that* critical of a problem - I could always copile from command line, but I don't want to lose an ability of double clicking compilation errors to jump to file I need to edit. I don't do a lot of code editing on Centos obviously, but sometimes some errors are produced that are not present on Ubuntu or Windows and debugging/fixing them through command line will be too much work.

So far I see some choices I can take but I an not very familiar with either of them

1) Cross compile from fresher Centos distro. How do I do that, is that possible?

2) Use some other application to make fixes in my code. Is there anything that is reasonably possible to install to work with qt5 toolchain?

3) Somehow fix qtcreator 2.5 to work with qt5 versions (so far internet says me it's not possible)

4) Maybe somewhow circumvent lack of opengl to launch qtcreator 3?

Comment: 1) Have you checked whether Qt Creator 3 can be compiled without its bits that require QtQuick2? 2) Have you tried using a software OpenGL rasterizer (MESA's llvmpipe, ...)?

Comment: Interesting suggestions, thanks :) I will have to check these